# Displaying a normalized image in RGB

Tags: image, image-processing

This is the result of a normalizatiopn of an image of size 24x24x3. I am not sure what kind of normalization was used. Would anybody have an idea how to display this image in RGB (preferably in Python)?

```
>#Array shape: (24, 24, 3)
0.69684684 0.20122847 -0.94488907
0.01537156 -0.52671105 -1.14623404
0.46452573 -0.09304496 -0.66610372
1.13051295 0.83623952 0.27866885
-0.03109266 -0.06206881 -0.48024684
0.17025231 0.06183579 -0.10853303
0.97563219 0.69684684 0.35610920
0.32513306 -0.04658074 -0.51122296
0.06183579 -0.44927070 -0.89842486
0.77428722 0.20122847 -0.41829452
1.19246531 0.68135881 -0.26341379
1.08404875 0.63489455 -0.51122296
0.92916799 0.38708535 -0.49573490
0.30964500 -0.20146148 -0.79000831
-0.51122296 -0.92940098 -1.23916245
-1.13074601 -1.42501938 -1.59538817
-1.36306715 -1.50245976 -1.68831670
-1.44050753 -1.53343594 -1.65734053
-1.50245976 -1.61087632 -1.68831670
-1.54892397 -1.62636435 -1.68831670
-1.71929288 -1.73478091 -1.78124511
-1.78124511 -1.79673314 -1.81222129
-1.79673314 -1.78124511 -1.78124511
-1.84319746 -1.81222129 -1.81222129
# New slice
1.17697716 0.71233493 -0.54219913
0.44903767 -0.07755689 -0.82098448
0.18574038 -0.37183031 -1.14623404
1.06856060 0.71233493 -0.12402111
1.54869103 1.36283410 0.61940646
1.06856060 0.80526340 0.26318076
0.97563219 0.55745417 0.07732386
0.29415691 -0.12402111 -0.63512760
0.17025231 -0.23243764 -0.80549639
0.40257344 -0.06206881 -0.83647257
0.72782302 0.18574038 -0.88293678
1.42478633 0.75879914 -0.48024684
1.33185792 0.60391843 -0.41829452
1.00660837 0.34062114 -0.52671105
0.34062114 -0.17048533 -0.86744869
-0.27890185 -0.66610372 -1.14623404
-0.52671105 -0.77452028 -1.11525786
-0.51122296 -0.69707990 -0.97586524
-0.58866334 -0.77452028 -1.03781748
-0.61963952 -0.79000831 -0.99135327
-1.28562677 -1.39404321 -1.50245976
-1.70380473 -1.76575708 -1.79673314
-1.79673314 -1.81222129 -1.79673314
-1.82770932 -1.81222129 -1.81222129
# New slice
1.68808365 1.34734595 0.17025231
1.33185792 0.85172760 -0.10853303
1.13051295 0.55745417 -0.55768722
1.30088174 0.88270378 -0.40280646
1.45576251 1.16148913 -0.12402111
1.30088174 0.86721569 -0.23243764
0.74331111 0.18574038 -0.63512760
0.27866885 -0.15499726 -0.86744869
0.20122847 -0.04658074 -0.80549639
0.48001382 0.17025231 -0.66610372
0.69684684 0.10830002 -0.86744869
1.19246531 0.30964500 -0.75903219
1.51771486 0.58843035 -0.48024684
1.50222671 0.71233493 -0.40280646
1.00660837 0.38708535 -0.68159181
0.18574038 -0.24792571 -1.05330563
-0.68159181 -1.02232945 -1.44050753
-0.74354410 -1.02232945 -1.33209097
-0.49573490 -0.75903219 -1.20818639
-0.46475875 -0.68159181 -1.02232945
-0.44927070 -0.63512760 -0.82098448
-1.37855518 -1.50245976 -1.53343594
-1.75026894 -1.82770932 -1.78124511
-1.81222129 -1.82770932 -1.79673314
# New slice
1.64161944 1.44027448 0.44903767
1.88942862 1.54869103 0.44903767
1.85845244 1.36283410 0.04634771
1.81198823 1.40929830 -0.15499726
1.76552403 1.44027448 -0.17048533
1.61064327 1.09953678 -0.35634223
1.22344136 0.63489455 -0.49573490
0.32513306 -0.06206881 -1.03781748
0.34062114 0.18574038 -0.74354410
0.63489455 0.38708535 -0.46475875
0.77428722 0.12378809 -0.68159181
1.26990569 0.24769269 -0.58866334
1.62613130 0.60391843 -0.46475875
1.64161944 0.75879914 -0.49573490
1.31636989 0.63489455 -0.65061563
0.82075149 0.30964500 -0.69707990
-0.27890185 -0.68159181 -1.22367442
-0.66610372 -1.02232945 -1.39404321
-0.32536608 -0.61963952 -1.16172218
-0.55768722 -0.82098448 -1.23916245
-0.58866334 -0.82098448 -1.05330563
-1.17721021 -1.34757900 -1.39404321
-1.70380473 -1.81222129 -1.75026894
-1.79673314 -1.81222129 -1.76575708
# New slice
0.96014416 0.88270378 0.32513306
1.34734595 1.17697716 0.40257344
1.78101206 1.61064327 0.69684684
1.87394059 1.68808365 0.63489455
1.64161944 1.47125065 0.35610920
1.88942862 1.64161944 0.58843035
1.84296441 1.57966709 0.44903767
1.36283410 1.11502492 -0.06206881
0.96014416 0.74331111 -0.37183031
0.91367990 0.54196614 -0.46475875
0.88270378 0.18574038 -0.63512760
1.28539371 0.35610920 -0.40280646
1.37832212 0.55745417 -0.54219913
1.50222671 0.74331111 -0.46475875
1.28539371 0.55745417 -0.63512760
1.26990569 0.63489455 -0.46475875
0.72782302 0.18574038 -0.75903219
-0.51122296 -0.94488907 -1.53343594
-0.82098448 -1.13074601 -1.56441212
-0.51122296 -0.75903219 -1.14623404
-0.60415143 -0.80549639 -1.06879365
-1.11525786 -1.25465059 -1.36306715
-1.62636435 -1.68831670 -1.73478091
-1.76575708 -1.81222129 -1.75026894
# New slice
-0.92940098 -0.97586524 -1.19269824
0.13927616 0.01537156 -0.46475875
0.75879914 0.63489455 0.04634771
1.23892951 1.16148913 0.44903767
1.68808365 1.59515524 0.82075149
1.54869103 1.44027448 0.63489455
1.70357168 1.53320289 0.61940646
1.54869103 1.33185792 0.29415691
1.68808365 1.40929830 0.32513306
1.30088174 0.88270378 -0.18597341
1.17697716 0.55745417 -0.44927070
1.16148913 0.43354958 -0.54219913
1.47125065 0.83623952 -0.32536608
1.68808365 1.02209640 -0.15499726
1.50222671 0.75879914 -0.35634223
1.36283410 0.63489455 -0.43378261
1.16148913 0.51098996 -0.57317525
0.58843035 0.07732386 -0.77452028
-0.38731837 -0.72805601 -1.20818639
-0.77452028 -1.03781748 -1.42501938
-0.55768722 -0.77452028 -1.08428180
-0.96037716 -1.08428180 -1.28562677
-1.47148359 -1.54892397 -1.67282856
-1.57990015 -1.65734053 -1.62636435
# New slice
-1.78124511 -1.81222129 -1.84319746
-1.34757900 -1.44050753 -1.61087632
-0.04658074 -0.15499726 -0.57317525
0.54196614 0.41806152 -0.20146148
0.96014416 0.80526340 0.03085964
1.50222671 1.34734595 0.49550188
1.67259562 1.45576251 0.72782302
1.64161944 1.42478633 0.69684684
1.76552403 1.51771486 0.63489455
1.44027448 1.11502492 0.06183579
1.54869103 1.11502492 -0.06206881
1.57966709 1.03758454 -0.20146148
1.62613130 1.06856060 -0.18597341
1.65710747 1.03758454 -0.17048533
1.57966709 0.83623952 -0.26341379
1.50222671 0.72782302 -0.27890185
1.28539371 0.55745417 -0.41829452
1.05307257 0.44903767 -0.38731837
0.09281194 -0.30987802 -0.88293678
-0.43378261 -0.77452028 -1.25465059
-0.65061563 -0.92940098 -1.31660283
-0.94488907 -1.13074601 -1.42501938
-1.05330563 -1.19269824 -1.36306715
-1.03781748 -1.14623404 -1.25465059
# New slice
-1.73478091 -1.75026894 -1.76575708
-1.78124511 -1.82770932 -1.82770932
-1.36306715 -1.44050753 -1.57990015
0.13927616 0.01537156 -0.43378261
0.72782302 0.52647805 -0.20146148
0.86721569 0.61940646 -0.29438993
0.99112028 0.71233493 0.07732386
1.44027448 1.17697716 0.63489455
1.65710747 1.45576251 0.71233493
1.73454785 1.57966709 0.55745417
1.47125065 1.19246531 -0.04658074
1.68808365 1.33185792 -0.03109266
1.73454785 1.28539371 -0.01560459
1.65710747 1.08404875 -0.12402111
1.57966709 0.85172760 -0.21694955
1.42478633 0.63489455 -0.32536608
1.39381027 0.60391843 -0.29438993
1.23892951 0.55745417 -0.24792571
0.27866885 -0.20146148 -0.86744869
-0.03109266 -0.46475875 -1.05330563
-0.27890185 -0.63512760 -1.11525786
-0.69707990 -0.97586524 -1.37855518
-0.60415143 -0.82098448 -1.14623404
-0.88293678 -1.03781748 -1.33209097
# New slice
-1.78124511 -1.79673314 -1.75026894
-1.76575708 -1.78124511 -1.68831670
-1.78124511 -1.84319746 -1.84319746
-1.19269824 -1.33209097 -1.51794779
0.52647805 0.30964500 -0.32536608
0.97563219 0.72782302 -0.20146148
1.00660837 0.72782302 -0.01560459
0.94465607 0.69684684 0.07732386
1.26990569 1.11502492 0.37159729
1.68808365 1.57966709 0.65038264
1.62613130 1.47125065 0.35610920
1.68808365 1.47125065 0.23220462
1.61064327 1.22344136 -0.06206881
1.73454785 1.19246531 -0.00011651
1.50222671 0.82075149 -0.23243764
1.39381027 0.61940646 -0.30987802
1.37832212 0.57294226 -0.27890185
1.16148913 0.44903767 -0.35634223
0.35610920 -0.18597341 -0.92940098
-0.03109266 -0.52671105 -1.19269824
0.26318076 -0.17048533 -0.74354410
-0.21694955 -0.57317525 -1.05330563
-0.58866334 -0.86744869 -1.25465059
-0.38731837 -0.57317525 -1.03781748
# New slice
-1.82770932 -1.82770932 -1.75026894
-1.81222129 -1.82770932 -1.65734053
-1.73478091 -1.82770932 -1.76575708
-1.56441212 -1.70380473 -1.79673314
0.54196614 0.34062114 -0.18597341
1.51771486 1.30088174 0.40257344
1.54869103 1.33185792 0.40257344
1.40929830 1.25441754 0.38708535
1.50222671 1.39381027 0.60391843
1.40929830 1.31636989 0.51098996
1.42478633 1.30088174 0.40257344
1.59515524 1.39381027 0.38708535
1.54869103 1.22344136 0.03085964
1.40929830 0.92916799 -0.20146148
0.99112028 0.37159729 -0.65061563
0.83623952 0.12378809 -0.80549639
0.54196614 -0.20146148 -1.03781748
0.29415691 -0.37183031 -1.19269824
0.21671654 -0.37183031 -1.19269824
0.29415691 -0.24792571 -1.00684142
0.06183579 -0.40280646 -1.06879365
-0.10853303 -0.49573490 -1.06879365
-0.17048533 -0.49573490 -0.99135327
-0.32536608 -0.54219913 -1.08428180
# New slice
-1.81222129 -1.84319746 -1.76575708
-1.79673314 -1.84319746 -1.70380473
-1.75026894 -1.82770932 -1.78124511
-1.64185250 -1.78124511 -1.84319746
0.06183579 -0.09304496 -0.52671105
1.67259562 1.50222671 0.66587073
1.57966709 1.44027448 0.37159729
1.50222671 1.39381027 0.37159729
1.48673868 1.42478633 0.58843035
1.78101206 1.71905982 0.97563219
1.56417906 1.47125065 0.72782302
1.33185792 1.14600098 0.29415691
0.94465607 0.61940646 -0.44927070
0.68135881 0.24769269 -0.80549639
0.46452573 -0.07755689 -1.06879365
0.63489455 0.04634771 -0.91391295
0.65038264 0.07732386 -0.86744869
0.94465607 0.37159729 -0.55768722
1.16148913 0.57294226 -0.30987802
0.97563219 0.44903767 -0.37183031
0.35610920 -0.10853303 -0.83647257
-0.26341379 -0.65061563 -1.28562677
-0.43378261 -0.77452028 -1.33209097
-0.37183031 -0.63512760 -1.16172218
# New slice
-1.78124511 -1.81222129 -1.79673314
-1.75026894 -1.82770932 -1.81222129
-1.71929288 -1.81222129 -1.79673314
-1.67282856 -1.81222129 -1.84319746
-0.68159181 -0.79000831 -1.09976983
1.34734595 1.23892951 0.49550188
1.56417906 1.48673868 0.43354958
1.50222671 1.44027448 0.43354958
1.51771486 1.45576251 0.63489455
1.64161944 1.54869103 0.82075149
1.73454785 1.59515524 0.80526340
1.76552403 1.56417906 0.68135881
1.36283410 1.05307257 0.06183579
1.09953678 0.69684684 -0.29438993
1.14600098 0.66587073 -0.32536608
1.44027448 0.97563219 -0.03109266
1.34734595 0.94465607 -0.10853303
1.20795333 0.75879914 -0.26341379
0.99112028 0.38708535 -0.52671105
0.88270378 0.35610920 -0.49573490
0.85172760 0.38708535 -0.37183031
0.06183579 -0.32536608 -0.99135327
-0.37183031 -0.71256793 -1.30111480
-0.40280646 -0.69707990 -1.17721021
# New slice
-1.67282856 -1.71929288 -1.76575708
-1.62636435 -1.71929288 -1.79673314
-1.59538817 -1.71929288 -1.73478091
-1.62636435 -1.73478091 -1.81222129
-1.39404321 -1.47148359 -1.67282856
0.69684684 0.65038264 -0.01560459
1.70357168 1.65710747 0.71233493
1.57966709 1.51771486 0.60391843
1.70357168 1.65710747 0.86721569
1.71905982 1.61064327 0.83623952
1.68808365 1.48673868 0.55745417
1.62613130 1.33185792 0.27866885
1.57966709 1.25441754 0.34062114
1.51771486 1.13051295 0.23220462
1.40929830 1.00660837 0.04634771
1.40929830 1.02209640 -0.01560459
1.42478633 1.14600098 0.01537156
1.22344136 0.86721569 -0.21694955
1.03758454 0.44903767 -0.48024684
0.66587073 0.13927616 -0.71256793
0.58843035 0.13927616 -0.61963952
0.30964500 -0.06206881 -0.72805601
-0.09304496 -0.41829452 -1.00684142
0.09281194 -0.21694955 -0.68159181
# New slice
-1.48697174 -1.57990015 -1.73478091
-1.42501938 -1.51794779 -1.79673314
-1.40953135 -1.53343594 -1.71929288
-1.37855518 -1.50245976 -1.68831670
-1.36306715 -1.47148359 -1.79673314
-0.52671105 -0.61963952 -1.22367442
1.00660837 0.91367990 0.01537156
1.53320289 1.45576251 0.55745417
1.75003600 1.65710747 0.88270378
1.75003600 1.62613130 0.86721569
1.64161944 1.47125065 0.60391843
1.68808365 1.50222671 0.55745417
1.68808365 1.51771486 0.78977531
1.82747638 1.70357168 1.08404875
1.82747638 1.71905982 1.08404875
1.92040479 1.76552403 0.99112028
1.87394059 1.59515524 0.63489455
1.11502492 0.61940646 -0.38731837
1.02209640 0.37159729 -0.48024684
0.89819181 0.32513306 -0.48024684
0.58843035 0.13927616 -0.58866334
0.26318076 -0.04658074 -0.71256793
0.20122847 -0.03109266 -0.65061563
0.07732386 -0.20146148 -0.77452028
# New slice
-1.14623404 -1.27013862 -1.61087632
-1.13074601 -1.22367442 -1.70380473
-1.13074601 -1.25465059 -1.59538817
-1.13074601 -1.28562677 -1.56441212
-1.05330563 -1.20818639 -1.64185250
-0.60415143 -0.75903219 -1.45599556
0.74331111 0.63489455 -0.23243764
0.91367990 0.82075149 -0.04658074
1.17697716 1.05307257 0.30964500
1.56417906 1.45576251 0.74331111
1.34734595 1.22344136 0.49550188
1.68808365 1.57966709 0.83623952
1.65710747 1.61064327 1.03758454
1.64161944 1.70357168 1.26990569
1.64161944 1.75003600 1.36283410
1.79650021 1.76552403 1.22344136
1.68808365 1.36283410 0.57294226
1.19246531 0.54196614 -0.37183031
1.11502492 0.37159729 -0.43378261
0.92916799 0.32513306 -0.43378261
0.49550188 0.07732386 -0.61963952
0.23220462 -0.00011651 -0.65061563
0.24769269 0.13927616 -0.44927070
0.13927616 -0.04658074 -0.66610372
# New slice
-1.05330563 -1.19269824 -1.54892397
-0.86744869 -0.96037716 -1.45599556
-0.89842486 -1.03781748 -1.42501938
-0.96037716 -1.13074601 -1.48697174
-0.94488907 -1.11525786 -1.57990015
-0.61963952 -0.79000831 -1.50245976
0.80526340 0.71233493 -0.09304496
0.82075149 0.75879914 0.01537156
-0.01560459 -0.10853303 -0.71256793
0.71233493 0.61940646 0.06183579
0.91367990 0.82075149 0.21671654
0.88270378 0.78977531 0.13927616
1.34734595 1.25441754 0.71233493
1.57966709 1.57966709 1.14600098
1.67259562 1.70357168 1.30088174
1.22344136 1.08404875 0.54196614
1.36283410 0.91367990 0.12378809
1.26990569 0.58843035 -0.34085417
1.26990569 0.52647805 -0.34085417
0.97563219 0.38708535 -0.40280646
0.37159729 -0.01560459 -0.71256793
-0.00011651 -0.20146148 -0.79000831
-0.01560459 -0.07755689 -0.60415143
0.55745417 0.44903767 -0.09304496
# New slice
-0.74354410 -0.88293678 -1.33209097
-0.94488907 -1.03781748 -1.57990015
-0.94488907 -1.08428180 -1.51794779
-0.75903219 -0.92940098 -1.34757900
-0.80549639 -1.00684142 -1.54892397
-0.58866334 -0.77452028 -1.47148359
0.57294226 0.46452573 -0.24792571
0.75879914 0.71233493 0.10830002
0.01537156 -0.06206881 -0.54219913
-0.75903219 -0.85196060 -1.20818639
0.35610920 0.27866885 -0.17048533
1.56417906 1.48673868 0.94465607
1.84296441 1.70357168 1.19246531
1.75003600 1.67259562 1.23892951
1.71905982 1.64161944 1.20795333
1.31636989 1.08404875 0.52647805
1.40929830 0.89819181 0.12378809
1.26990569 0.55745417 -0.37183031
1.30088174 0.54196614 -0.37183031
0.96014416 0.37159729 -0.44927070
0.48001382 0.09281194 -0.57317525
-0.46475875 -0.63512760 -1.11525786
-0.18597341 -0.18597341 -0.60415143
0.72782302 0.71233493 0.27866885
# New slice
-0.03109266 -0.17048533 -0.72805601
-0.32536608 -0.43378261 -1.02232945
-0.63512760 -0.79000831 -1.30111480
-0.66610372 -0.86744869 -1.34757900
-0.41829452 -0.61963952 -1.19269824
0.20122847 -0.00011651 -0.69707990
0.77428722 0.66587073 0.01537156
0.46452573 0.40257344 -0.10853303
-0.07755689 -0.17048533 -0.54219913
0.17025231 0.07732386 -0.26341379
-0.34085417 -0.43378261 -0.79000831
0.58843035 0.51098996 0.06183579
0.99112028 0.80526340 0.30964500
1.00660837 0.86721569 0.41806152
1.40929830 1.25441754 0.78977531
1.70357168 1.40929830 0.82075149
1.26990569 0.71233493 -0.07755689
1.22344136 0.49550188 -0.46475875
1.36283410 0.63489455 -0.30987802
1.16148913 0.60391843 -0.23243764
0.46452573 0.12378809 -0.52671105
-0.86744869 -0.99135327 -1.33209097
-0.63512760 -0.60415143 -0.89842486
-0.13950919 -0.09304496 -0.41829452
# New slice
0.06183579 -0.07755689 -0.71256793
0.03085964 -0.09304496 -0.72805601
-0.04658074 -0.20146148 -0.79000831
0.51098996 0.30964500 -0.24792571
0.63489455 0.41806152 -0.18597341
0.82075149 0.60391843 -0.06206881
0.82075149 0.68135881 0.06183579
0.48001382 0.38708535 -0.09304496
-0.69707990 -0.82098448 -1.11525786
-0.48024684 -0.61963952 -0.94488907
-0.20146148 -0.32536608 -0.69707990
-0.52671105 -0.65061563 -1.08428180
-0.04658074 -0.24792571 -0.75903219
0.66587073 0.48001382 -0.01560459
1.17697716 0.94465607 0.43354958
1.50222671 1.14600098 0.49550188
1.17697716 0.57294226 -0.23243764
1.25441754 0.54196614 -0.41829452
1.25441754 0.61940646 -0.35634223
1.22344136 0.71233493 -0.12402111
0.46452573 0.15476424 -0.44927070
-1.00684142 -1.11525786 -1.39404321
-1.39404321 -1.36306715 -1.54892397
-0.94488907 -0.89842486 -1.13074601
# New slice
0.12378809 -0.03109266 -0.72805601
0.06183579 -0.07755689 -0.75903219
-0.03109266 -0.20146148 -0.83647257
0.23220462 0.03085964 -0.58866334
0.18574038 -0.03109266 -0.66610372
-0.15499726 -0.38731837 -1.00684142
-0.01560459 -0.18597341 -0.85196060
0.24769269 0.10830002 -0.44927070
0.49550188 0.34062114 -0.12402111
-0.68159181 -0.85196060 -1.20818639
-0.65061563 -0.80549639 -1.23916245
-0.41829452 -0.58866334 -1.08428180
-0.26341379 -0.46475875 -0.99135327
0.04634771 -0.15499726 -0.68159181
0.60391843 0.35610920 -0.21694955
1.03758454 0.61940646 -0.06206881
1.28539371 0.66587073 -0.17048533
1.26990569 0.60391843 -0.35634223
1.19246531 0.66587073 -0.30987802
1.23892951 0.80526340 -0.00011651
0.49550188 0.21671654 -0.37183031
-0.96037716 -1.06879365 -1.34757900
-1.56441212 -1.56441212 -1.70380473
-1.08428180 -1.05330563 -1.25465059
# New slice
0.26318076 0.09281194 -0.60415143
0.21671654 0.06183579 -0.63512760
0.32513306 0.15476424 -0.54219913
0.24769269 0.04634771 -0.63512760
0.20122847 -0.03109266 -0.68159181
0.18574038 -0.07755689 -0.72805601
0.40257344 0.20122847 -0.51122296
0.34062114 0.17025231 -0.51122296
0.27866885 0.07732386 -0.49573490
0.26318076 0.06183579 -0.46475875
-0.04658074 -0.24792571 -0.80549639
-0.07755689 -0.26341379 -0.85196060
-0.30987802 -0.46475875 -1.02232945
-0.23243764 -0.40280646 -0.96037716
-0.17048533 -0.41829452 -1.05330563
0.32513306 -0.07755689 -0.82098448
1.33185792 0.75879914 -0.12402111
1.45576251 0.86721569 -0.07755689
1.53320289 1.09953678 0.17025231
1.42478633 1.08404875 0.29415691
0.32513306 0.09281194 -0.48024684
-1.08428180 -1.20818639 -1.48697174
-1.59538817 -1.65734053 -1.78124511
-1.27013862 -1.27013862 -1.44050753
# New slice
0.20122847 0.01537156 -0.68159181
0.30964500 0.13927616 -0.57317525
0.32513306 0.15476424 -0.57317525
0.38708535 0.18574038 -0.54219913
0.44903767 0.20122847 -0.46475875
0.48001382 0.20122847 -0.44927070
0.40257344 0.17025231 -0.60415143
0.44903767 0.24769269 -0.55768722
0.41806152 0.18574038 -0.51122296
0.37159729 0.13927616 -0.51122296
0.34062114 0.12378809 -0.55768722
0.17025231 -0.03109266 -0.72805601
-0.00011651 -0.10853303 -0.69707990
-0.12402111 -0.27890185 -0.86744869
-0.15499726 -0.40280646 -1.08428180
0.21671654 -0.18597341 -0.99135327
1.22344136 0.66587073 -0.24792571
1.57966709 1.05307257 0.09281194
1.50222671 1.14600098 0.24769269
1.20795333 0.89819181 0.15476424
0.09281194 -0.12402111 -0.66610372
-0.75903219 -0.91391295 -1.25465059
-1.28562677 -1.39404321 -1.59538817
-0.82098448 -0.88293678 -1.08428180
# New slice
0.27866885 0.07732386 -0.61963952
0.29415691 0.13927616 -0.60415143
0.34062114 0.17025231 -0.58866334
0.49550188 0.29415691 -0.44927070
0.49550188 0.23220462 -0.46475875
0.51098996 0.23220462 -0.43378261
0.51098996 0.26318076 -0.52671105
0.37159729 0.13927616 -0.71256793
0.65038264 0.35610920 -0.40280646
0.60391843 0.29415691 -0.43378261
0.55745417 0.27866885 -0.48024684
0.43354958 0.21671654 -0.54219913
0.18574038 0.04634771 -0.60415143
-0.00011651 -0.18597341 -0.85196060
-0.00011651 -0.26341379 -1.02232945
0.41806152 0.04634771 -0.82098448
1.03758454 0.55745417 -0.40280646
1.61064327 1.19246531 0.26318076
1.64161944 1.39381027 0.65038264
1.40929830 1.19246531 0.58843035
-0.17048533 -0.37183031 -0.80549639
-0.97586524 -1.11525786 -1.45599556
-0.91391295 -1.02232945 -1.31660283
0.13927616 0.03085964 -0.26341379
# New slice
0.26318076 0.04634771 -0.63512760
0.41806152 0.26318076 -0.49573490
0.30964500 0.13927616 -0.60415143
0.54196614 0.32513306 -0.40280646
0.51098996 0.26318076 -0.44927070
0.44903767 0.18574038 -0.52671105
0.48001382 0.24769269 -0.54219913
0.51098996 0.24769269 -0.55768722
0.85172760 0.48001382 -0.27890185
0.82075149 0.43354958 -0.32536608
0.71233493 0.40257344 -0.38731837
0.65038264 0.44903767 -0.35634223
0.65038264 0.43354958 -0.29438993
0.18574038 -0.07755689 -0.82098448
0.52647805 0.21671654 -0.60415143
0.49550188 0.17025231 -0.74354410
1.26990569 0.89819181 -0.09304496
1.82747638 1.54869103 0.68135881
1.59515524 1.44027448 0.89819181
0.89819181 0.74331111 0.34062114
-0.52671105 -0.66610372 -0.97586524
-1.20818639 -1.30111480 -1.62636435
-0.20146148 -0.27890185 -0.71256793
-0.21694955 -0.35634223 -0.79000831
# New slice
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like this image is indeed in RGB Color Space! Here is my Result! I guess it is a Fish or a Frog!

Original Image : 24x24 
[image]

Zoomed In Image
[image]

I used the following C++ Code:

```
Mat mSrc,mDst;
Size szImageSize(24,24);    

mSrc= Mat(szImageSize,CV_64FC3,vfIArray[0]);    

normalize(mSrc,mDst,0,255,NORM_MINMAX,CV_8UC3);     

imshow("Output image",mDst);
```

Python Equivalent will be like this:

```
cv2.normalize(mSrc,mDst,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX,cv2.CV_8UC3);
```

Comment: Great, it works! Just tiny typo, NORM_MINMAX -> cv2.NORM_MINMAX